# Composition of two relations

Tags: relations

Among all students in a classroom we have a binary relations $\mathcal {R,S}$. 

Student **A** is in relation with student **B**, formally **(A,B) $\in$ $\mathcal R$,** iff -
 "**A** sits in the same row as **B** and **B** is not to the left of **A**"

Student **A** is in relation with student **B**, formally **(A,B) $\in$ $\mathcal S$,** iff -
 "**B** sits in the second row (regardless of **A**)" 

Not all seats have to be occupied.

I have to decide whether the composition of these relations, $\mathcal S \circ \mathcal R$, is  reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive. I only need help with the composition of these relations. What will the final relation look like? How to solve composition of relations like this (howto would be appreciated). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it helpful to think of composition of relations as multiplication of Boolean matrices, where addition of truth values is disjunction and multiplication is conjunction: $(i,k)\in\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$ if and only if there is at least one element $j$ such that both $(i,j)\in\mathcal R$ and $(j,k)\in\mathcal S$. In the present case, $(i,k)\in\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$ if and only if there is a student $j$ such that $i$ sits in the same row as $j$ and $j$ is not to the left of $i$, and $k$ sits in the second row. Since $j$ doesn't occur in the second condition, we can choose $j=i$ to fulfill the first condition; so $(i,k)\in\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$ if and only if $k$ sits in the second row.

This relation is not reflexive unless all students sit in the second row. It's not symmetric unless all students sit in the second row or all students don't sit in the second row. It's not antisymmetric unless at most one student sits in the second row. It's transitive since $(j,k)\in\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$ alone implies $(i,k)\in\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$.